# Angular-Kendo UI treeview, issue on node expansion

Tags: angularjs, kendo-treeview

I'm facing this alleged Kendo UI treeview bug in the Angular version. It's specific to the k-template option.

The bug shows up on their online demo - http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/angular

Just expand Item 2, and suddenly the text becomes `{{dataItem.text}}`.

Here's the html I'm using on my page:

```
 <div id="treeview" kendo-tree-view="nav.treeview"             
                k-options="nav.treeOptions"
                k-data-source="nav.reportsTreeDataSource"
                k-on-change="nav.onTreeSelect(dataItem)">         
    <span k-template>
        <span data-toggle-tree-icons></span>
    </span>       
 </div>
```

[image: kendo treeview]

Has anyone comes across this, or found an updated Kendo lib ?

thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The k-template issue has been rectified in the last Kendo UI release, .1328. 
This demo here a still a version behind however - http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/angular .

Answer (score 2):

A workaround.

Html :

```
<div kendo-tree-view="tree"
k-data-source="treeData"
k-template="treeTemplate">
```

JS :

```
$scope.treeTemplate = function (dataItem) {
    return dataItem.item.text;
}
```

Alex